# Cleaning up junk characters in MSSQL sql dump

Tags: sql-server, regex, encoding

I am supporting a migration from MSSQL to Postgres. I am just the guy in the middle, and don't have actual access to the MSSQL server, which doesn't make things easier. I was able to persuade the MSSQL people to do an SQL export (instead of a .bak file), and already know how to deal with MS-specific weirdness in the file. However, the file also has a whole bunch of junk characters at the end of each line, like so:

```
 INSERT [dbo].[Client_Balances] ([client_id], [Total Invoices], [Total Debits], [Total Payments], [Total Credits], [Balance Forward]) VALUES (N'D0000006492', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)))਍䤀一匀䔀刀吀 嬀搀戀漀崀⸀嬀䌀氀椀攀渀琀开䈀愀氀愀渀挀攀猀崀 ⠀嬀挀氀椀攀渀琀开>椀搀崀Ⰰ 嬀吀漀琀愀氀 䤀渀瘀漀椀挀攀猀崀Ⰰ 嬀吀漀琀愀氀 䐀攀戀椀琀猀崀Ⰰ 嬀吀漀琀愀氀 倀愀礀洀攀渀琀猀崀Ⰰ 嬀吀漀琀愀氀 䌀爀攀搀椀琀猀崀Ⰰ 嬀䈀愀氀愀渀挀攀 䘀漀爀眀愀爀搀崀⤀ 嘀䄀䰀唀䔀匀 ⠀一✀䐀　　
    　　　㄀㄀㐀㌀　✀Ⰰ 䌀䄀匀吀⠀㈀㠀　⸀　　 䄀匀 䐀攀挀椀洀愀氀⠀㌀㠀Ⰰ ㈀⤀⤀Ⰰ 䌀䄀匀吀⠀　⸀　　 䄀匀 䐀攀挀椀洀愀氀⠀㌀㠀Ⰰ ㈀⤀⤀Ⰰ 䌀䄀匀吀⠀㌀㄀㐀⸀　　 䄀匀 䐀攀挀椀洀愀氀⠀㌀㠀Ⰰ ㈀⤀⤀Ⰰ 䌀䄀匀吀⠀　⸀　　 䄀匀
     䐀攀挀椀洀愀氀⠀㌀㠀Ⰰ ㈀⤀⤀Ⰰ 䌀䄀匀吀⠀ⴀ㌀㐀⸀　　 䄀匀 䐀攀挀椀洀愀氀⠀㌀㠀Ⰰ ㈀⤀⤀⤀ഀ
```

Any ideas on how to clean this up directly in the text .sql file? Manual is not an option - the file contains 13.1 million lines. The characters aren't all the same, either, so I can't figure it out - can I write a regex that includes all of these?

Comment: (1) what programming language are you using to clean up the file? (2) what's the general format of the file? Does it always begin with `INSERT ... ` then some junk text at the end?

Comment: @mvw - No, there is no foreign language data in the database. I also wondered about encoding.

Comment: @ZoffDino the file is plaintext. I was thinking about just doing it in a shell or in vi - but am definitely open to better ideas!

Comment: I think it is no Chinese, but some "corrupt" UTF16 data, maybe ANSI "interpreted" as UTF16.

Comment: @stribizhev would i change my vi environment to test if that's the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the file using latin1 or utf8 encoding, you can see that the "garbage" characters are actually miss-aligned "INSERT" statements. My guess is that unix-style line endings (LF) was converted to windows-style line endings (CRLF) without regard to the 2-byte encoding.

```
INSERT [dbo].[Client_Balances] ([client_id], [Total Invoices], [Total Debits], [Total Payments], [Total Credits], [Balance Forward]) VALUES (N'D0000006492', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Client_Balances] ([client_id], [Total Invoices], [Total Debits], [Total Payments], [Total Credits], [Balance Forward]) VALUES (N'D0000011430', CAST(280.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(314.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)), CAST(-34.00 AS Decimal(38, 2)))
```

You could try to reverse it, by opening the file as latin1 encoding in windows format, and saving it back as unix format. Then reopen the file using utf16 encoding. (Replacing CRLF with LF should also work)

In vim:

```
:e ++enc=latin1 ++ff=dos data.sql
:w ++enc=latin1 ++ff=unix data2.sql
:e ++enc=utf16le data2.sql
```

(Or try `utf16be`).

Comment: (I deleted my old comments after figuring out they were just user error)